# Override the values in ini file using environment variable in python uvicorn fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am using a ini file for log configuration , i want to override log_level based on environment where we are deploying. so can it be oveeriden based on env variable

logging.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console

[formatters]
keys=json

[formatter_json]
class = pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format={"timestamp": "%(asctime)s", "level": "%(levelname)s", "message": "%(message)s"}

[handlers]
keys=console

[handler_console]
class=logging.StreamHandler
formatter=json
stream=sys.stdout
```

Here i want to ovveride value of logger_root.level to DEBUG in prod and DEBUG in dev environments

I am passing this file to uvicorn using below command in dockerfile

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080","--log-config","logging.ini"]
```